# How to refresh rollup fields automatically in data verse using power automate flow

Tags: power-automate, rollup, dataverse

When an item created in child table the count will be automatically updated in rollup field in parent table using power automate flow

I have tried with flow with using azure key vault but I want to do it by flow only when a new row is created